# Reading the result of guide.beginshowmessagebox

Tags: c#, vb.net, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, xna

At the moment i have a message box popping up when my XNA game in launched whilst the user is playing music via the media player. It has two buttons, yes and no. What i need to do is determine which button the user has pressed so i can use an IF statement to do the relevant thing depending upon the result. At the moment my code is:

```
    Public Sub playmusic()
    FrameworkDispatcher.Update()
    If MediaPlayer.GameHasControl = False Then

        'Add everything below when you want to show the message box
        Dim MBOPTIONS As New List(Of String)()
        MBOPTIONS.Add("Yes")
        MBOPTIONS.Add("No")
        Dim result As IAsyncResult = Guide.BeginShowMessageBox("Music request", "Do you want to stop your music and play the in-game music?", MBOPTIONS, 0, MessageBoxIcon.Alert, Nothing, Nothing)

        result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne()


        Dim choice As System.Nullable(Of Integer) = Guide.EndShowMessageBox(result)

        If choice.HasValue Then
            If choice.Value = 0 Then
                MediaPlayer.Stop()
                sounds = True


            Else

                sounds = False

            End If
        End If



    End If






End Sub
```

Can anybody help me in terms of what code i need to read the result?